# Passing table row element to a js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a bootstrap table which element are loaded from a database. 
I have  a js function to delete a table row from data base, so I add a  button in each row of the table.

```
  <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>id</th>
                          <th>client</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>
                         <?php
                         require("config.php");
                         // Create connection
                         $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
                         // Check connection
                         if ($conn->connect_error) {
                             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                         }

                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                         $result = $conn->query($sql);

                         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                             // output data of each row
                             while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                                          $user_id=$row[0];
                                          $user_name=$row[1];
                                ?>

                               <tr>
                                 <!--here showing results in the table -->
                                   <td><?php echo $user_id;  ?></td>
                                   <td ><?php echo $user_name;  ?></td>

                                   <td>

                                       <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" value="Cancella sin id" onclick="deleteFunction()"/>


                                   </td>
                               </tr>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

How can I pass to **deleteFucntion** the id or user_name in order to use them into Javascipt like this:

```
function deleteFunction() {

    var username = #MY_ROW_USERNAME;
    ....
}
```

Comment: if you add the button to every row when you looping through you could add the id into the `onclick` of the button `onclick="functionDelete(id)"`

Answer (score 0):

TD's should look like this

```
<td id="user_name_<?=$user_id?>" onClick="deleteFunction(<?=$user_id?>)"><?=$user_name?></td>
```

Delete function like this

```
function deleteFunction(user_id) {
   var username = document.getElementById('user_name_'+user_id).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: this would always get the first one in the list..no matter which one you clicked on!

Comment: You are not suppose to have elements with the same id? Shouldnt you have a different id everytime ie. user_name_1, user_name_2, etc. If so combining your comment and mine would be what you need

Comment: but if you have the id why would you need the name... The ID should always be unique un-like a name can be the same.... And if you want to reference it in a data base the ID is the best way to do it.

Comment: For OP, change your <td> to <td id="user_name_<?=$user_id?>">  That would give you original id's to pass into click functions and in turn to access the proper nodes

Comment: Edited original answer to reflect current state